# Heroku db:pull taps gem pulls previously db:push'd data instead of current data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, taps

I'm using the taps gem, and I am trying to use heroku db:pull to pull down my current production database.

However, when I pull, it pulls down a database that I db:push'd almost 3 months ago, instead of the current DB.

Is there a way to specify that I want the latest? Is it possible to remove that old database?

Thanks for your time

EDIT: I'm using MySQL locally, and I am aware of pgbackups and am trying to avoid the pg dumping associated with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple deployment environments (ie staging vs production), make sure you specify the right one with db:pull --app productionAppName.

If you have unused tables in the production environment that you want to get rid of, your two options are:

1. create a migration to drop the table
2. "heroku run rails console" and manually drop the tables.

both techniques are described in this post:
[Heroku Drop Table Rails Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964824/heroku-drop-table-rails-help)

hope it helps!

Comment: I do have multiple environments, and I am pulling from the correct one

Answer (score 0):

There was only 1 DB on Heroku, but it had remnant tables from a long time ago that were not overwritten when I pushed the new database up.

TL;DR => it merged the old DB with the new

Comment: i had that same issue.  i've edited my original answer and included the link i used to resolve it.  do not go the manual route unless your db migrations are messed up.